# Is it possible to drop a primary key index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

Is it possible to drop a primary key index in MySQL (version 5.1.47).

This is to optimize the insert performance.

Comment: If you end up duplicating a primary key, you won't find out until you try to recreate the primary key afterwards.

Comment: I want to drop the index on the primary key and not the primary key itself.

Comment: The index is used to keep the field unique. You can't drop the index and keep the uniqueness requirement.

Answer (score 7):

If you're sure this is what you want to do (note Paul Tomblin's comment on your question), then from the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) docs:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

> DROP PRIMARY KEY drops the primary key. If there is no primary key, an error occurs.